# How do you change tables for Windows Phone app using Mobile Services?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on building a Windows Phone 8.1 app using Mobile Services, and I can't seem to figure out how to change the table from the default TodoItems table to one of the tables I previously created.  I created a SQL database that I've hooked up to my mobile services project, and this database already has tables created.  I've followed the mobile services tutorials from Azure (found [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/)), but I can't find any documentation on how to change the table being used.  Both the table I want to use and the default table that's currently being used are in the same database, so I know that my app is connected to the database I created.  I thought that I might need to edit MainPage.cs file under the Shared directory (MainPage.xaml in the WindowsPhone project links to the MainPage.cs file in the Shared project), but I can't seem to add a reference to my Service project in my WindowsPhone project.  I guess that's not what I'm supposed to do.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tables being created by the mobile service are by default in a different database schema. So the table you created might be called dbo.MyTable while the TodoItem table is more like MyMobileService.ToDoItem.

If you have direct access to the SQL database, you can change the schema for your table.

Using the examples above: ALTER SCHEMA MyMobileService TRANSFER dbo.MyTable

Which back end are you using JavaScript or .NET?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I've actually abandoned mobile services and decided to use web api instead.  It seems a lot easier to use.  I'm using .NET for the backend.